# Set Report Dataset Parameter in code

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a large number of Reports running as a `ServerReport` in a `ReportViewer` control on an `ASPX` page.

Each report uses the same 3 shared Datasets. Each Dataset has at least one Parameter.

I need to pass a value (at runtime) to each of these Datasets' Parameter, but cannot fathom how to do so.

I tried using `ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetDataSources()` but it lies and says there are zero Datasets when I know there are some...

I know I could add a hidden Parameter to each Report, but that would mean modifying dozens of Reports, all in *exactly* the same way, which strikes me as breaking the *DRY* principle...

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: How have you managed to pass the parameter to the dataset in the reports WITHOUT having a parameter in the report itself?

Comment: The shared Dataset has a Parameter (which gets passed to the underlying stored proc) which is NULL by default. This works.

Comment: It works in the sense that it executes, but without the report passing in the parameter, presumably this means the report has no way of influencing the dataset, even when previewing in SSDT.

Comment: Yes, the report doesn't pass a value, as I was hoping to pass the value directly to the dataset itself.... Looks like this will have to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few options that occur to me.

Option 1: add the parameter to the reports, as you suggest. I don't think this is breaking any principles, since the report is the unit of encapsulation, and it is the report itself that you design to be parameterisable (or not). You as a caller of the report from C# shouldn't need to know about the dataset behind the scenes, as it is the report your interact with.

Alternatively, you need to find a way that the report is unaware that the dataset is parameterised at runtime, so...

Option 2: Make a stored procedure that takes the parameter, does what the dataset does, and puts the results in a table. Programmatically call this prior to calling any reports. The report datasets can then take their data from the table of results.

Option 3: Pop the run-time parameter into a scratch table at run time, so that the dataset can pick it up for itself from the database  without it needing to be a parameter for the dataset.

Option 4: Explore [caching Shared Datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/cache-shared-datasets-ssrs).
This sounds like it might be a dead end, but there's a chance you could find a way to make all the reports use a freshly cached version of the data.

Comment: Thanks Rich. Option 0 would have been my choice - pass the value to the Dataset, but that doesn't seem possible... Think I'm stuck with Option 1 as 2 & 3 seem a lot more work with little gain. Option 4 doesn't solve the problem, but does have merits where users might look at lots of Reports...

Comment: "...the report is the unit of encapsulation..." - I'd argue that it isn't when using a shared dataset... Surely that object becomes the Lowest Common Denominator?

Comment: If you can programmatically call the dataset without going through a report, your argument would be valid. But the report provides the only interface to your calling code- how it gets its data is up to the report. It just so happens that the designer of the reports has decided to further factor away a bit of that implementation. The report is the unit of encapsulation as far as the calling C# is concerned, because that's all it gets to interact with. Similarly if a bunch of reports chose to use a shared assembly to decide the colours, that's up to the reports, not to the calling code.

Comment: I agree with what you say. Maybe the designer has 'hidden' too much useful functionality behind the Report...?

Comment: We don't want our reports to be too useful :-)

Comment: Ok, so what I need is the source code for the Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer so that I can add that functionality myself. Where do I get it?

Comment: You could try an open source reporting api, you may have more luck with that

Comment: I created a source-code file using dotPeek, but it didn't help. It obtains some info about datasets via a SOAP conversation with the server, but doesn't have the datasets within it - they stay server-side.

Comment: I had to 'bite the bullet' and add a hidden param to 20 reports. Maybe MS should add the concept of 'master report' - similar to a master page in ASP...??